# How to run Visual Studio Code as root without --user-data-dir argument?

Tags: command-line, bash, visual-studio-code

I can run VS code with following command

```
sudo code ~/.zshrc --user-data-dir="/root/.vscode"
```

But it annoyed me.
How do I config it so I can run VScode as root without --user-data-dir argument?

Comment: Why at all run it as root. There are NO VALID REASONs for running applications as root.

Comment: This is really a bad idea. root is for configuring and maintaning the system, not for running applications. Change your workflow

Comment: I know. But sometime I want to configure txt file such as /etc/fstab via gui instead of vim.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with adding the `-H` parameter for sudo:

```
 -H, --set-home
             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
             variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
             password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be
             the default behavior.
```

That would be:

```
sudo -H code ~/.zshrc
```

This way, `~/.zshrc` would still refer to your calling users `.zshrc`, but the home directory for `code` would appear as the one for root (`~root`).

Although what you are doing (running vs code as root) sounds wrong. Maybe you have your reasons, but in general it is not recommended to run programs as root.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :

1. `sudo chown -R <current_user> <path_to_your_vscode_installation_directory>`
2. As per your requirement, user will be 
   user : **root**
3. You can find path of vscode directory using following command : 
   `whereis code`
   e.g. path could be : ****/usr/share/code****
4. So final command will be : 
   `sudo chown -R root /usr/share/code`

This will run vscode as ***root*** without the need of ***--user-data-dir*** argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking for this answer for a long time, and pieced together a few different answers to come to a simple script to run once after each VSCode update:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '/^#!.*/a set -- "$@" "--no-sandbox" "--user-data-dir=~"' /usr/bin/code
sed -i '/^ELECTRON=.*/i VSCODE_PATH="/usr/share/code"' /usr/bin/code
sed -i 's!/code !&--no-sandbox --user-data-dir=~ !' /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

The first sed always appends the fix parameters. The second sed fixes the application launch path. These result in VSCode starting correctly from the command line.
However, the last sed fixes the menu item so that launching it from the (debian) start menu results in the app loading.